# How to bump a question up if you have low reputation

Tags: support, reputation, bump

Some other questions said that you can bump up a question by editing it, but another answer said that of you have low reputation points, it will not bump up, and I think my question has not been bumped up. Low reputation edits, according to [Do pending edits get bumped to the front page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80186/do-pending-edits-get-bumped-to-the-front-page), are called pending edits and don't count for bumping up.  How can I get my question bumped back up; I have added to it and edited it, it is at this link:
[Why is my function only concating the first indexes to my array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25613330/why-is-my-function-only-concating-the-first-indexes-to-my-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Edits to your own question are applied immediately and result in your question being bumped.

Comment: @RossRidge, thanks for the reply, but that didn't work, would that count As a pending edit?

Comment: It did work. You're edit of about 45 minutes ago (UTC 22:00) caused it  it to be sorted with other questions posted or modified around that time.

Comment: It just doesn't have much to do with reputation or editing.  When you post a question with a lot of CAPITAL LETTERS then *everybody* knows to avoid your post from a mere glance at the title.  You are advertizing the kind of skill that horrible aunt had, always wanting to be heard but never having anything interesting to say.

Comment: @HansPassant, I did not have the capital letters at first, then it did not get an answer, so I thought maybe it would be better and more attractive to the eye. Thanks for the comment, I will change it.

Comment: Thanks, @rossridge. I couldn't see it though when I went to unanswered and newest.

Comment: You should not *seek* to have your questions bumped.

Answer (score 18):

It got bumped when you edited it. It got bumped a *lot*, because you edited it *a lot*.

...the problem is, most of your edits were kinda pointless. If folks didn't care much about reading it the *first* time, you didn't really give them any good reasons to do so the *second* or *sixth* or *tenth* times you edited.

...In fact, you probably made it worse by sticking a big block of ALL CAPS words at the start of the title. Nothing screams "I'M SELLING SOMETHING OF DUBIOUS VALUE" like a meaningless ALL CAPS PREFIX.

Adding "thanks" to the end or misspelled content-free updates aren't helping much either.

[Here are some suggestions for edits that will make your post more attractive.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you're gonna bump, you might as well make it worthwhile.

Answer (score 9):

All questions are bumped up to the [active tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active) when they are edited.

If a user has less than 2k reputation and he/she suggests an edit in somebody else's post, the suggested-edit needs to be approved to bump up the question. If the suggestion is rejected, the question won't bump up.

Self edits will bump up posts immediately.

Be aware that a bumping is a consequence of an edit that should have been made to improve the post's quality. Editing posts with minor or irrelevant details for the sake of attracting more visibility is not considered a best practice.