# What qualities make me receive downvotes?

Tags: discussion, question-quality, downvote-reason

On questions I ask, and some answers I give, esp. if I have a link (even if I say some of the text from the link and the link is for greater than can be written out and source), but those with a link have been deleted, too.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25613330/why-is-my-function-only-concating-the-first-indexes-to-my-array-in-javascript) question received at least two downvotes, and probably two upvotes to make it 0, as an example of my past down votes. [This one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270481/how-to-bump-a-question-up-if-you-have-low-reputation), I think, received four downvotes and one upvote.

What do I need to improve on?

Comment: One of it is incorrect spelling :P ...

Comment: Why should spelling cause a down-vote? Should it not cause that person to edit instead? It would not be that the question is wrong.

Comment: @JavaScriptArray I think the spelling reference mostly refers to the fact that "receive" is spelt incorrectly in your question title :)

Comment: I think the reasons you got downvoted on your first question is because you don't seem to have tried debugging properly, you just left a code dump and are asking people to debug your program. The second question could be answered by reading the help center and other Meta questions.

Comment: Well, @eddie_cat, thanks for the comment. I did try for more than an hour to find the bug and couldn't; it could end up being a general error

Comment: 1)Votes here on Meta work differently than other places...do a quick search to find them rules here (or ask me to do it and I'll -1 the request :)  )  2) link's tend to break over time, if Stackoverflow is intended to be a reference site, what good is a broken link five years from now.  3)  There appears to be a lot of confusion regarding your posts and what you are actually asking.  Possible some of those downvotes were from before your editting/clarification (including edits to your title to make it more clear)

Comment: @Twelfth, thanks, I will try to work on clarity, but would links not be good for additional info after the main idea from the link has been said? Stack overflow has a link button, I think for that(even if links are not to be used just for going to)?

Comment: Some more advice: Avoid overly complex and broad questions like "My project doesn't work" even if this is the case. Break it down into specific problems, solve all you can solve by yourself and ask the rest on SO in single question. SO wants to have one problem per question. As a bonus you'll get more reputation if you post more (good) questions.

Comment: It seems to be not a good sign about the openness of the MSO community when clear question asking for learning and advice are downvoted. I don't think it's a good way.

Answer (score 13):

Your pattern of thought is very scattered.

Nobody knows what "This is similar results at their worst!" means, no matter how much you bold it, make it all capital letters or put it in the title of your question, all three of which are major stylistic errors.

In general, your Stack Overflow post is very difficult to understand.  We don't need a blow-by-blow of your troubleshooting thought process, and you aggravated the problem by getting mired in a small edit war over details that are not significant.

Why did you link [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270481/how-to-bump-a-question-up-if-you-have-low-reputation) in your question here, when it doesn't seem to have any relevance?  Is that why you made all of those insignificant edits, to bump your post?  If that's what you did, then you missed [this answer's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270484/102937) whole point.

All in all, I think you would have a better time of it if you spend some time reading over other people's questions and answers, and reading the Help Center a few times.  Try to find those questions that the community responds to favorably, and study those to find out how a good question is structured.  You'll then be in a better position to ask your next question, and have it responded to by the community more favorably.

Oh, and yes, *spelling does matter.*  Professionals make sure that they use proper spelling, grammar and punctuation in all of their correspondence, if they expect to be taken seriously.  They write in clear, concise prose.  They make sure they do everything they can to be clearly understood.  You do want to be a professional, right?

Comment: I am still a beginner without vast knowledge of javascript, and less of other languages, so most other questions I cannot understand because I am not that advanced, yet.

Comment: It's not about your Javascript experience.  I never mentioned that.

Comment: Well, it would make it hard to study questions.

Comment: Study their question style, the way they are asked, how they are presented, what elements they include.  Most importantly, *what elements they leave out:* good question writers know how to *edit* themselves.  There is such a thing as too much information.

Comment: I guess that I do have trouble leaving out details; it would make it more clear to leave out more details. That is one of my problems for sure.

Comment: It's all about *relevance.*  For example, when we ask for code, we don't ask for the entire project; we only ask for that code that is essential to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I also have a bad memory of when I only gave code of the part where I thought there was the bug; the bug was hidden in another part and not where the error occurred.

Comment: The complexity of the question or the answer is not the important factor.  The difference between a bad question or answer and a good one is to only place what is relevant in your text but provide sufficient detail to allow someone to follow your thought process.  Oh, and to make sure someone else hasn't already asked the question first!